# Registering Actuate iServer Express email account

Tags: birt

When I follow the steps to register the email account it points me to iServer -> bin where mailinst.exe apparently is. I need this to complete the registration.

Does anyone know where this .exe is?

I've created an account on the Actuate Forum but have to wait to be validated which can apparently "normally takes a few hours, but in some cases it may take us several days to confirm your status".

can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What platform have you installed iServer Express on?  mailinst is a Windows executable used to bind an iServer e-mail profile to an Exchange profile.  If you did not install on Windows, you are not likely to see this tool in the bin directory.

Comment: Installed iServer Express on Windows.Have followed all the steps but still unable to locate mailinst.exe

Comment: Sorru so long in getting back to you.  Looks like the docs online are incorrect and Exchange mail (MAPI) is not supported on iServer Express.